# Finding $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left((1+\frac{1}{n^2})(1+\frac{2^2}{n^2})^2\cdots(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2})^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Calculate the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left((1+\frac{1}{n^2})(1+\frac{2^2}{n^2})^2\cdots(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2})^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

> My attempt:

Let
$$y=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left((1+\frac{1}{n^2})(1+\frac{2^2}{n^2})^2\cdots(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2})^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left((1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{\frac{1}{n}}(1+\frac{2^2}{n^2})^{\frac{2}{n}}\cdots(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2})^{\frac{n}{n}}\right)$$
Now, taking logarithm on both sides to get:  $$\log y=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}\log(1+(\frac{k}{n})^2)$$
But I am unable to convert it into integral form (riemann sum to integral ) as the expression $\frac{k}{n}$ is present instead of $\frac{1}{n}$. Can someone please help me in solving this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You missed to bring down $\frac{1}{n}$ after taking $log$ on both sides.

Comment: @AkshatSharma I accounted that in the 2nd step where each expression is now raised to $\frac{k}{n}$

Comment: Oh yes, does the sum even converge then?

Comment: Pardon me...Is this question correct?...because without $\frac{1}{n}$, sum does not even converge to Reimann integral.....If you give the source of this question, it would be helpful ....

Answer (score 2):

By your work $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{2^2}{n^2}\right)^2\cdots\left(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}=$$
$$=e^{\int\limits_0^1x\ln(1+x^2)dx}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^1\ln(1+x)dx}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\left((1+x)\ln(1+x)-x\right)|_0^1}=e^{\ln2-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt e}.$$
Can you end it now?

I used your work and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2\right)\frac{1}{n}=\int\limits_0^1x\ln(1+x^2)dx.$$
Since $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{e}}\right)^n=+\infty,$$ we see that starting limit does not exist.

Comment: @Martund I know. See please better my post.

Comment: then  you have used raised to $\frac{1}{n^2}$ in the solution. Why is that so?

Comment: @s1mple I used the definition of the Riemann integral. We need also $\Delta x$, for which we need also $\frac{1}{n}.$

Comment: I don't understand your point here, I am sorry. also the answer is given to be $\frac{4}{e}$.

Comment: @s1mple I think in your answer is wrong. I added something. See now.

Comment: @s1mple, to answer your question "Why is that so?" above, it is used $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (\cdots)^{\frac1n}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} [(\cdots)^{\frac1{n^2}}]^{n}$

Answer (score 1):

Considert the factors

$$\left (1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right )^k,\,\, n/2< k \le n.$$

Each of these is greater than

$$\left (1+\frac{(n/2)^2}{n^2}\right )^{n/2} = \left (\frac{5}{4}\right)^{n/2}.$$

There are more than $n/2$ such factors. Thus the product of these factors is at least $(5/4)^{n^2/4}.$ Now take the $n$th root to get $(5/4)^{n/4}\to \infty.$ Thus the limit of the original expression is $\infty.$